# Data not saved into database even though command executed successfully in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2

I know, this seemed to be a million time asked question, but I am asking again because, earlier answers doesn't solve my problem.

I have this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[My_Save_Command_SP] 
    @Param1 varchar (50),
    @Param2 varchar (500),
    @Param3 varchar(500),
    @Param4 varchar (500),
    @Param5 varchar (500),
    @Param6 varchar (500) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE  @ParamID BIGINT 
    SET @ParamID = 0

    SET @ParamID = (SELECT ISNULL(ParamID,0) AS ParamID FROM t_MyTable WHERE Param1 = @Param1)

    IF @ParamID > 0 
    BEGIN
       UPDATE t_MyTable 
       SET Param2 = @Param2, Param3 = @Param3, Param4 = @Param4, 
           Param5 = @Param5, Param6 = @Param6
       WHERE Param1 = @Param1 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      SET @ParamID = (select ISNULL(MAX(ParamID),0) AS ParamID from t_MyTable) 
      SET @ParamID = @ParamID + 1

      INSERT INTO t_MyTable (ParamID, Param1, Param2, Param3, Param4, Param5, Param6) 
      VALUES (@ParamID, @Param1, @Param2, @Param3, @Param4, @Param5, @Param6)
    END
END
```

And below is the back end code-

```
Boolean bResult = false;
Int32 nCounter = 0;
Int32 nAffectedRow = -1;

using (SqlConnection connection = DBAccessDA.CreateConnection())
{
    SqlCommand command = DBAccessDA.CreateCommand(connection);

    SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
    DBAccessDA.CreateStoredprocedure(command, "My_Save_Command_SP");

    for (int i = 0; i < pList.Count; i++)
    {
        nAffectedRow = -1;
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        DBAccessDA.AddInParameter(command, "@Param1", SqlDbType.VarChar, pList[i].Param1);
        DBAccessDA.AddInParameter(command, "@Param2", SqlDbType.VarChar, pList[i].Param2);
        DBAccessDA.AddInParameter(command, "@Param3", SqlDbType.VarChar, pList[i].Param3);
        DBAccessDA.AddInParameter(command, "@Param4", SqlDbType.VarChar, pList[i].Param4);
        DBAccessDA.AddInParameter(command, "@Param5", SqlDbType.VarChar, pList[i].Param5);
        DBAccessDA.AddInParameter(command, "@Param6", SqlDbType.VarChar, pList[i].Param6);

        // This line returns -1  
        nAffectedRow = DBAccessDA.ExecuteNonQuery(command, transaction); 

        if (nAffectedRow > 0)
        {
           nCounter++;
        }
     }

     if (nCounter == pList.Count)
     {
        transaction.Commit();
        bResult = true;
     }
     else
     {
        transaction.Rollback();
        bResult = false;
     }
  }
```

If I run the stored procedure from SQL query window with the same parameters, it inserts the data, BUT NOT from the code. Please help.  Thanks.

Comment: could you please tell what is the DBAccessDA?

Comment: It's difficult to tell, but at first glance it seems you do not pass the parameter size. You could use `SQL Profiler` to get the statement executed on the server with your command.

Comment: @heq, DBAccessDA is a class which provides database connections, commands, add parameters in a command etc. In short, it is used to remove the need to write similar database related codes .

Comment: @danradu, i checked the profiler and the SP of the profiler runs and adds data into DB when executed from sql query window. Also, I am using this same approach (without parameter size) in other operations in this same application and they works fine.

Comment: I had another look at your code and I think is the `SET NOCOUNT ON` statement in your SP which is the problem. The number of affected records is 0 and your back-end code rolls back the transaction. Try removing that statement from the SP.

Comment: @danradu, BOSS !!! you are the life savior. It works !!! How can I Accept your answer as you posted in a comment.

Comment: @marc_s, i am using winforms. By the way, DAN RAUD solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks every one for your time. Cheers !!!

Answer (score 1):

From @dan's comment:

> I think is the `SET NOCOUNT ON` statement in your SP which is the problem. The number of affected records is 0 and your back-end code rolls back the transaction. Try removing that statement from the SP.